# Message from injected script to content script does not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building chrome extension and I need to establish two-way communication between `injected.js` and `content_script.js`. I have permission for using `tabs` in `manifest.json`. What I have tried for starters is to make a message from `injected` to `content_script`. I am using this:

```
// Content script
window.addEventListener("getChromeData", function(data) {
  console.log( data ) // CustomEvent {isTrusted: false, detail: null, type: "getChromeData", target: Window, currentTarget: Window, …}
}, false);

// Injected script
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("getChromeData", {data: 'whatever'}));
```

The problem is, that I have a response in the content script but not that `data` object that I am sending from `injected`. I have received only `CustomEvent` object without that data.

Can someone guide me through this, what I have to do to achieve one-way message, and possibly two-way, from `content_script` to `injected`?

Edit:

After suggestion to edit `data` into `detail` property, here is what I have

```
// Injected script
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("getChromeData", {detail: {
        first: 're',
        two: 'two'
}}));

// Content script
window.addEventListener("getChromeData", function(data) {
  console.log( data ) // Still getting CustomEvent {isTrusted: false, detail: null, type: "getChromeData", target: Window, currentTarget: Window, …}
}, false);
```

I have compiled, reloaded extension, and reloaded the page. Still, my return object has `detail` that points to the `null` value.

Comment: [Custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) have `detail` property, not `data`

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. I have changed it, but `detail` still points to the null value.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have edited the original post to see what I have done.

Comment: Is it Firefox? AFAIK it requires `cloneInto({detail: { ...... } , document)`

Comment: It's chrome. I am making a chrome extension.

Comment: Assuming you really reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page and the code you're using is exactly the same as posted in the second snippet, it can only be a bug in Chrome, but I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Oh, alright. Well, many thanks to you for this help that you have provided to me!

Comment: Other than a bug in Chrome it can be that the site redefines/hooks dispatchEvent or CustomEvent API. You can circumvent it by injecting the code at document_start and saving the original method references in local variables then invoke them via savedRef.call(window, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. What I did is that I have removed and installed the extension, and it worked. That was my last try on the problem and it worked.